# Select json value frob jsonb column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Here is my inserting request to my postgres table:

```
insert into pay_process (created, execution_time, updated, bundle_id, processing_status, xxi_balance)
values (current_timestamp, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 1, 'SUCCESS',
        '"{\"balances\": [{\"bs_day\": \"2021-02-12\", \"balance\": 1167.18}, {\"bs_day\": \"2021-02-13\", \"balance\": 4796.45}]}"');
```

xxi_balance has jsonb type. I need to select my balances array, I use the request for that:

```
select xxi_balance::json->'balances' as balances from pay_process;
```

But it returns nothing. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You are storing one large JSON scalar, not a nested JSON object. You need to remove the double quotes surrounding the whole value and the escaped double quotes inside the value:

```
insert into pay_process 
 (created, execution_time, updated, bundle_id, processing_status, xxi_balance)
values 
  (current_timestamp, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 1, 'SUCCESS',
   '{"balances": [{"bs_day": "2021-02-12", "balance": 1167.18}, {"bs_day": "2021-02-13", "balance": 4796.45}]}');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4eeaabc9c0bc31c92e1c4b9ebb0cffa9)